# unable to parse message of type [...] error in custom message

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to send a custom message from a model plugin to another model plugin. The two plugins are linked to same model.
The code compiles well, but when I run gazebo GUI it shows me this error in topic visualisation:

> unable to parse message of type[robot_brain_fitness_msgs.msgs.robotDataRequest]

I do not why, can you guys help me...thanks in advance :)

here is the source code

---

in subfolder msgs

/msgs/robot_brain_fitness.proto

```
package robot_brain_fitness_msgs.msgs;
message robotDataRequest
{
   required double fitness = 1; 
}
```

/msgs/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
set(PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS)
foreach(ITR ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  if(ITR MATCHES ".*gazebo-[0-9.]+$")
    set(PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS "${ITR}/gazebo/msgs/proto")
  endif()
endforeach()
set (msgs
  robot_brain_fitness.proto
  ${PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS}/vector2d.proto
  ${PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS}/header.proto
  ${PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS}/time.proto
)
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${msgs})
add_library(robot_brain_fitness_msgs SHARED ${PROTO_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(robot_brain_fitness_msgs ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
```

---

in root folder

plugin1.cc

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "robot_brain_fitness.pb.h"

namespace gazebo
{   

typedef const boost::shared_ptr
    <const robot_brain_fitness_msgs::msgs::robotDataRequest>   robotDataRequestPtr;


    class ReceiveMsgPlugin : public ModelPlugin
    {

    private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;
             physics::ModelPtr model;
             transport::SubscriberPtr subscriber;
             transport::NodePtr node;

    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/) 
    {    
        //subscriber = node->Subscribe("~/robotData", &ReceiveMsgPlugin::create, this);
                  
        this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
            ( boost::bind(&ReceiveMsgPlugin::OnUpdate, this, _1));
    }
    /*public: void create(robotDataRequestPtr &msg)
    {
        std::cout << "fitness : " <<msg->fitness() << "\n";
    
    }*/     
    public: void OnUpdate(const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/)
    {
    
    }
};
 GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(ReceiveMsgPlugin)
 }
```

plugin2.cc

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "robot_brain_fitness.pb.h"

namespace gazebo
{   
 class SendMsgPlugin : public ModelPlugin
 {
private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;
         physics::ModelPtr model;
         transport::PublisherPtr publisher;
         transport::NodePtr node;

   public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/) 
   {
    this->model = _parent;
  
     node = transport::NodePtr(new transport::Node());
    
     node->Init(this->model->GetWorld()->GetName());
     
     this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
        ( boost::bind(&SendMsgPlugin::OnUpdate, this, _1));

   }

    public: void OnUpdate(const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/)
    {
        robot_brain_fitness_msgs::msgs::robotDataRequest request;
        request.set_fitness(10);
        publisher = node->Advertise
          <robot_brain_fitness_msgs::msgs::robotDataRequest>("~/robotData");
        publisher->Publish(request);
    }
};
GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(SendMsgPlugin)  
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8 FATAL_ERROR)
FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.40 COMPONENTS system REQUIRED )
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")

include (FindPkgConfig)
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
  pkg_check_modules(GAZEBO gazebo)
  pkg_check_modules(SDF sdformat)
endif()

include_directories(
  ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/msgs
  )
link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${SDF_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/msgs)
add_subdirectory(msgs)

add_library(plugin1 SHARED plugin1.cc)
target_link_libraries(plugin1 robot_brain_fitness_msgs 
${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES} ${SDF_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(plugin1 robot_brain_fitness_msgs)

add_library(plugin2 SHARED plugin2.cc)
target_link_libraries(plugin2 robot_brain_fitness_msgs ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES} ${SDF_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(plugin2 robot_brain_fitness_msgs)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7829/unable-to-parse-message-of-type-%5B...%5D-error-in-custom-message/) by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The problem is that the Gazebo GUI doesn't know about your custom message, so it can't display it in the topic visualizer. There is no easy solution. If you want to quickly see the content of the message, you can print it to the terminal (or to a log file) in your plugin.

This problem will be fixed in Gazebo 6, when we update the transport library.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1